# Gravity Form->Select Field->Add Option

Tags: select, dropdown, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

So Gravity List has a great option in its Drop Down User Interface that let's you add by typing a new option, kinda like an "other" option.

[Gravity List Field-Drop Down Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqCUT.png)

I want to do this with a normal Drop Down.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dropdown that is dynamically populated with taxonomy terms, including a term called "other".

When the "other" select option is chosen, conditional logic to a single line text field that will create a new taxonomy term on form submission.

On next use of the form, the dynamic list will have your new single line term too.

Keep using the "other" conditional route to add new options to select.